# C-function fwrite in 'r+'-mode on Samba share

Tags: samba, c, smb2

Since the switch from samba protocol SMB1 to SMB2, it seems that fwrite can't act in "r+"-mode on files on a mounted samba share anymore. Errno is set to EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported).

Whereas the "a+"-mode of fwrite works fine.

Anyone has an explanation for this?